# parse.com query a column inside the pointer

Tags: parse-platform

I subclassed Claim and Store. But the question would still be the same if it was not subclassed.

Its kind of a straight up question. I cant find it in the parse docs.

```
var q = from Claim in new ParseQuery<Claim>().Include("deal")
                    where Claim.Deal.Store== store
                    select Claim;
int count = await q.CountAsync();
```

It returns 0 but it should return 1.

This should be possible right ? because i already included the deal column.

Comment: you might need a nested query instead of the direct filter on the included class object property "Deal.Store".

Comment: @RobertRowntree you have an example of that ? I tried using 2 queries but it didnt work

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20151124023259/https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide/#queries-relational-queries    the old REST api docs show what u want . if u r using SDK then check analogous section of docs on the wayback arch